# VS 2013 C# latency in debug Oracle SQL queries

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, latency

I installed VS 2013 plus the Oracle ODAC and everything works beautifully when not in debug mode. Queries to the Oracle server run instantaneously. But in debug mode, the same query takes like 40 seconds to complete.

I'm using * Oracle 12.1.0 Client * VS 2013 c# * MS Windows Server 2012

Example code that runs fine when not in debug mode:

```
        con.ConnectMe();
        SQL = "select TITLE,FIRST,LAST,AMT,SAMT,FISCAL,SSN from schletters";
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(SQL, con.cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("SCHLETTERS");
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
        con.CloseMe();
```

Comment: what query?, what version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle Client 12.1.0. I updated my question with the query.